# How do I split this string with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Javascript:

```
var string = '(37.961523, -79.40918)';

//remove brackets: replace or regex? + remove whitespaces

array = string.split(',');

var split_1 = array[0];

var split_2 = array[1];
```

Output:

```
var split_1 = '37.961523';

var split_2 = '-79.40918';
```

Should I just use `string.replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace(/\s/g, '');` or RegEx?

Comment: if this format is NOT going to change, regex is definitely an overkill.

Comment: what is the question? what you have works

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
string.slice(1, -1).split(", ");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to extract both numbers at once.

```
var string = '(37.961523, -79.40918)';
var matches = string.match(/-?\d*\.\d*/g);
```

Answer (score 1):

You would probably like to use regular expressions in a case like this:

`str.match(/-?\d+(\.\d+)?/g); // [ '37.961523', '-79.40918' ]`

**EDIT** Fixed to address issue pointed out in comment below

Comment: Your regex would fail for any integer number less than 10 and greater than -10.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

If the `()` were `[]` you would have valid JSON. So what you could do is either change the code that is generating the coordinates to produce `[]` instead of `()`, or replace them with:

```
str = str.replace('(', '[').replace(')', ']')
```

Then you can use `JSON.parse` (also available as [external library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)) to create an array containing these coordinates, already parsed as numbers:

```
var coordinates = JSON.parse(str);
```