# Extract lat, lng from a variable length string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want extract lat. and longitude vals from a string like this:

```
var data = "(-20.210696507479017, -70.14000177383423),(-20.21202551027535, -70.14246940612793),(-20.21385790460967, -70.14066696166992),(-20.21168319245841, -70.13901472091675)"
```

How can I extract these pairs and push them into a array if these points can change in quantity?

Thanks

Comment: `JSON.parse('{coords:[' + data.replace(/\(/g, '[').replace(/\)/g, ']') + ']}')`

Comment: **Very** similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077840/how-do-i-split-this-string-with-javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the pairs, then split each pair and parse the values. This produces an array of objects that have a `lat` and `lng` property that are numbers:

```
var coors = data.split('),(');
for (var i = 0; i < coors.length; i++) {
  var c = coors[i].replace('(', '').replace(')', '').split(',');
  coors[i] = { lat: parseFloat(c[0]), lng: parseFloat(c[1]) };
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/EV2h4/

Answer (score 0):

Why not transform it into a json string array, then parse it to an object.

```
var data = "(-20.210696507479017, -70.14000177383423),(-20.21202551027535, -70.14246940612793),(-20.21385790460967, -70.14066696166992),(-20.21168319245841, -70.13901472091675)";
var arr = JSON.parse("[" + data.replace(/[)(]/g, "") + "]");
for(var x=0; x<arr.length-1; x+=2)
    console.log("lat " + arr[x] + ", lon " + arr[x+1]);
```

**edit** x+=2, good catch Iftah

Comment: you need to x+= 2 to process pairs, not x++

Comment: JSON parse is overkill here, if you remove the parenthesis then you ca just use split(',')

Comment: @Iftah - JSON.parse would allow for more advanced mangling in the future like using regex replace and creating an array of {lat: ##, lon: ##} objects. Using JSON.parse also allows the resulting elements to be typeof 'number' instead of 'string'.